# ACF Field Not Displaying in the Front End

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I created a custom ACF Field called 'url' under the user registration data section which will carry the facebook homepage of the user  . However when I try to use it in index.php template it is not working. It is showing no href link. I don't see anything wrong with the code.

```
     $author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');
     $test=get_field('url', 'user_'.$author_id);
      ?>
    <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $test; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $gravatar?></a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the id of user:

For example:

```
get_field('url', 'user_1');
```

This code returns the url field of user with id = 1

Comment: +1 - @Dev B - check out the **Get a value from different objects** portion of the [`get_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) docs for more information

Comment: So I Used 
           $author_id    = get_the_author_meta('ID');
 <?php $test=get_field('url', $author_id); ?>

 <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $test; ?>" target="_blank"><?php  echo $gravatar?></a></div>


Still there is no URL available in the href.

Comment: @Dev B do not use `$author_id` but `'user_' . $author_id;`

Comment: The issue is that I am the admin user and The custom field is available only to the authors.  What you are saying is that I should use like this:-

        $my_post = get_post( $id ); 
 $userid= $my_post->post_author;
 $test=get_field('amazon', $userid);

Comment: @Dev B. You just need to get the user id and add it to the string `'user_'`. And pass the result to `get_field` second parameter.

Comment: I am adding the code below. Please correct if possible. I still see the href empty.

Comment: Modified the code above. Please review. The href link is still showing nothing.

Comment: Nevermind. Issue resolved. Thanks to your second comment.